# How do I embed a slide deck from Slideshare

Tags: fieldtype, embeds

what´s the best way to embed an iframe from Slideshare into an entry? Here´s an example.

```
<iframe src="http://de.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/17368866" width="427"
height="356" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"
style="border:1px solid #CCC;border-width:1px 1px 0;margin-bottom:5px" allowfullscreen
webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen> </iframe>
```

I use Content Elements, but non ofthe sub fields CE offers will show the deck. So, I assue, that I need to add an extra field. Which one would be the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert the iFrame code into a normal Content Elements textarea field.

Comment: A normal Textarea field is not working, but when I switch within an RichText- or WYSIWYG-fields to code view and paste the iframe it works

Comment: What shows up when you use a normal textarea field? Is the iFrame code all on one line? Do you see an option to set the field to use None for formatting?